# Attach my action to F5/Refresh

Tags: eclipse-plugin, refresh

i'm writing a plugin for Eclipse and i would like to attach one of my actions to Eclipse F5/Refresh event.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach a IExecutionListener to the ICommandService. You will get notification of all the commands executed. You can look for the command id that you want (in this case org.eclipse.ui.file.refresh) and do your operation

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm really a eclipse newbie.

Comment: In the other comment you said you wanted to do it in the Package explorer. Can you specify what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: Just add my action to the package explorer refresh event. With the code on my comment i only get the refresh event if my view has the focus.

Comment: You can find an example here: http://sandipchitale.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/hooking-into-eclipse-command-execution.html (it uses other command id, but shows how to do it)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're writing this for Eclipse Helios (3.6).

In Eclipse help, in the Platform Plug-in Developer Guide -> Programmer's Guide -> Advanced resource concepts -> Refresh providers, there's an extension point.

```
org.eclipse.core.resources.refreshProviders
```

Your class has to extend RefreshProvider to use this extension.

Comment: Hi Gilbert! I'm not sure if it's what i'm looking for. It seems that that provider is useful for monitoring local resources, what i need is just know when the user has clicked in Eclipse refresh button or F5.

Comment: Hi MrCatacroquer.  I don't know that you have a choice.  Your refresh provider doesn't have to refresh anything.  You have to write an installMonitor method, but the method doesn't have to do anything other than let your code know that a refresh is taking place.  You can monitor the whole project, I suppose.  Does it matter to you where in the Package Explorer the refresh happens?

Comment: Hi Gilbert, i see.
What i place the following inside my plugin.xml
 
  <extension
         id="myRefreshProvider"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.refreshProviders">
      <refreshProvider
            name="Cool Refresh Provider"
            class="com.Test.TestRefreshProvider">
      </refreshProvider>
   </extension>

And the class com.Test.TestRefreshProvider extends RefreshProvider and 
overrides installMonitor method but i'm running it and nothing is going
through it... Am i missing something??

Comment: Hi MrCatacroquer.  This is difficult to discuss in a comment.  Your XML looks fine.  You're familiar with the concept of listeners in SWT, right?  Your installMonitor is a listener that implements IRefreshMonitor.  I've not actually worked with RefreshProvider.  I'm just reading the documentation.  I might have missed something too.

Answer (score 0):

According to Prakash G. R., I show the sample code.
Because the initialization code in Activator does not work if we need to use Workbench, therefore I use the startup extension point. The plugin.xml is

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
  <startup
        class="sampleplugin.MyStartUp">
  </startup>
</extension>
```

Therefore in MyStartUp class we add the ExecutionListener to ICommandService.
The important thing is that the ExecutionEvent in the preExecute method is not able to
extract the selection. This is different from usual ExecutionEvent in Command.
Therefore , the MyStartUp.java is

```
public class MyStartUp implements IStartup {

    @Override
    public void earlyStartup() {
        ICommandService service = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService    .class);
        service.addExecutionListener(
                new IExecutionListener() {

                    ...

                    @Override
                    public void postExecuteSuccess(String commandId,
                            Object returnValue) {

                      // do something post

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void preExecute(String commandId,
                            final ExecutionEvent event) {
                            if (org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_REFRESH.equals(commandId)    ) {

                                IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
                                IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
                                IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();

                                ISelection selection = page.getSelection();

                                // do something using selection

                            }
                    }

        });

    }

}
```

I use the

```
    IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();

    ISelection selection = page.getSelection();
```

instead of

```
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelectionChecked(event);
```

because the above reason. However, this is due to the Eclipse inner mechanism. 
The refresh event uses an old action mechanism and The ExternalActionManager call 
preExecute method directly in which the event has no data for selection.

I want the second formula

```
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelectionChecked(event);
```

may be available in preExecute method in the future.